# Passing Func<> to IQueryable vs Expression<Func<>>

Tags: c#, linq

I'm starting to look under the LINQ hood a little more, and I'm having trouble understanding some of the LINQ extension method overloads.

For example, lets say I'm querying a DbContext using .Where().  I'm always passing a standard Func<>, as opposed to an Expression<> of said Func<>.  Example query below:

```
var db = new MyContext();
var foo = db.products.Where(p => p.Category == "books");
```

Here is where I'm confused.  When I look at the available method signatures, I would assume the overload I'm using above would be returning me an IEnumerable...but it's actually returning an IQueryable.  How is this possible, if the IQueryable overload is expecting an Expression as opposed to just a Func?  It feels like the compiler is somehow helping me out by (in this case) building the Expression for me, but I can't find a resource that explains if this is the case.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework, then using a Func<> in your queries can be bad.  We had a situation where we were querying a database using a Func<> in the lamda.  The result was that EF returned the entire table to the client and then did the filtering using the Func<> on the client side.  You should definitely use Expression<Func<>> when using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It feels like the compiler is somehow helping me out by (in this case) building the Expression for me

Correct, the compiler is compiling the lambda into an `Expression` rather than a `Func`.

> I can't find a resource that explains if this is the case

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx):

> When a lambda expression is assigned to a variable of type `Expression<TDelegate>`, the compiler emits code to build an expression tree that represents the lambda expression.

Answer (score 3):

> It feels like the compiler is somehow helping me out by (in this case) building the Expression for me

That is exactly what is happening. The compiler can interpret lambdas (as long as they don't have a "statement body") as either delegates or expression trees. The `Queryable.Where<T>(this IQuerayble<T>, ...)` extension method takes precedence over the `Enumerable.Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T>, ...)` extension method, so the compiler chooses to interpret your predicate as an expression tree.

Comment: Thank you for answering what would have been my follow up question (that building the Expression takes precedence).

Comment: @gerg no, it isn't that "building the Expression" takes precedence; it is that `IQuerayble<T> : IEnumerable<T>`; it is `IQuerayble<T>` that takes precedence. The expression tree happens *after* method overload resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You're *not* passing a `Func` in that example.  You're passing an `Expression`.  A lambda can compile down into either a delegate or an expression, based on the context around it.  In this case the context around it is expecting an expression, so that is what the lambda compiles into.  If you actually did pass in a `Func` and not a lambda (which could be either) then you would get an `IEnumerable` for your result, not an `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can automatically build an expression tree for you from a lamba expression, and that is what's happening here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397951.aspx